# How to output filename after loading the file in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, file

I am doing a CNN project to estimate pitch from a spectrogram. The project is already finished and waiting to be presented to my institution, but I would like to improve a little detail to my work.

CNN that I have built must be tested using test (val) datas. I store the data in Google Drive (I build my CNN using Google Colab), and before doing testing with `do_test` method, I have to load the data. Path are given in the code snippet below.

I am able to load the data. The loaded data is then tested, but my problem is, I do not know which file that I have loaded. Testing result is exported to a Python DataFrame. DataFrame example output is attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Mb1ccVDecbg2a-uIoFZtH6BlQQ0ifA-/view?usp=sharing).

I want to put the filename of each file loaded and then put it to Dataframe output result, so I will know each output of a specific file. Right now, I can only know the overall data from 1 song without knowing which file is which (see DataFrame). What should I add to my code to get the filenames? Should I modify `image_data` code in function `get_image_and_label`?

Some (I hope) useful items:

1. Folder containing image. Folder link is given [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ia_FdFgLclLRs6LnqB263yNE7In1XQ-i?usp=sharing)
2. Folder containing labels can be accessed [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zGoY_WMT8Xz4dMS2rEpTIFNXDXgFjrHb?usp=sharing)
3. DataFrame output screenshot 
   [image: dataframe output]

Method `do_test`. This method is used to execute testing.

```
model = Sequential()
song_titles = "014_twinkle_twinkle 017_old_mcdonald 020_happy_birthday 022_brother_john 030_london_bridge".split()
image_data_train_global_path = "./drive/MyDrive/1117002_Code Skripsi/Dataset/Dataset TA_1_spectrograms/spectrogram_B_2/train/"
image_data_test_global_path = "./drive/MyDrive/1117002_Code Skripsi/Dataset/Dataset TA_1_spectrograms/spectrogram_B_2/val/"
label_global_path = "./drive/MyDrive/1117002_Code Skripsi/Dataset/Dataset TA_2_label_floor/"

def do_test(): 
  for title in song_titles:
    print("Song title: ", title)
    label_and_image_test = load_image_and_label(title, process='test') # this is where I load my data.
    images_test, labels_test = populate_test_data(label_and_image_test)
    X_test, y_test = label_processing(images_test, labels_test)

    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

    song_number = 0
    unique_pitch_result = []
    pitch_class_result = []
    distance_result = []

    while song_number <= (len(y_pred)-1):
      label_sequence = []
      for i in y_pred[song_number]: 
        max = np.max(i) 
        ind = np.argmax(i) 
        label_sequence.append(ind)

      result_pitch_sequence = [k for element in label_sequence for k,v in unique_pitch_dictionary.items() if element == v]
      unique_pitch = np.unique(result_pitch_sequence)
      unique_pitch = unique_pitch.tolist()
      
      if (title=="014_twinkle_twinkle"):
        s1 = s1_014_twinkle
      elif (title=="017_old_mcdonald"):
        s1 = s1_017_mcd
      elif (title=="020_happy_birthday"):
        s1 = s1_020_hbd
      elif (title=="022_brother_john"):
        s1 = s1_022_john
      elif (title=="030_london_bridge"):
        s1 = s1_030_london
      
      cost_matrix = DTW.dtw_cost_matrix(s1, result_pitch_sequence)

      distance = DTW.dtw_distance(cost_matrix)

      pitch_class = [v for element in unique_pitch for k,v in pitch_class_dictionary.items() if element == k]
      
      unique_pitch_result.append(unique_pitch) 
      pitch_class_result.append(pitch_class) 
      distance_result.append(distance)

      song_number+=1
      print("+"*100)

    df = DTW.test_result_dataframe(unique_pitch_result, pitch_class_result, distance_result, song_number)
    print(df)
    filename = title + " " + str(epochs) + " " + str(learning_rate) + " dataframe.xlsx"
    df.to_excel(filename)  
    print("*"*120)
```

Function `load_image_and_label`. This is used to get data path, then execute file loading from directory.

```
def load_image_and_label(title, process):
  print("Title: ", title)
  label_specific_path = label_global_path + title
  
  if (process == "train-test"):
    image_data_train_specific_path = image_data_train_global_path + title
    image_training_data = get_image_and_label(image_data_train_specific_path, label_specific_path)

  image_data_test_specific_path = image_data_test_global_path + title
  image_testing_data = get_image_and_label(image_data_test_specific_path, label_specific_path)

  if (process == "train-test"):
    return image_training_data, image_testing_data
  else:
    return image_testing_data
```

Function `get_image_and_label`. This is where I try to get my files. I think I have to modify something here to output the filename.

```
def get_image_and_label(image_path, label_path):
    print("Getting image data from: ", image_path)
    image_data = [] # contains array of loaded image and its label. Maybe, should I add code to append the filename here?
    tm = time.time()
    for img_item in os.listdir(image_path): #for every image in path
        try:
          img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_path, img_item))

          # preprocess image
          spectrogram_preprocessing = resize_recolor_spectrogram(img_array)

          # imread to array
          spectrogram_preprocessing = np.array(spectrogram_preprocessing)

          # image shape - transpose
          spectrogram_preprocessing = np.transpose(spectrogram_preprocessing)

          # extract image labels
          label = extract_pitch_label(os.path.join(label_path, img_item))

          image_data.append([spectrogram_preprocessing, label]) # add image data and its label to image_data array. What code should I add here to get filename?
        except Exception as e:
          raise e
    
    print("Got "+str(len(image_data))+" images from " + image_path + " in "+str(time.time() - tm)+ " seconds")
    print("-"*110)

    return image_data
```

This is the output if I have succeeded in loading my data.

```
Song title:  014_twinkle_twinkle
Title:  014_twinkle_twinkle
Getting image data from:  ./drive/MyDrive/1117002_Code Skripsi/Dataset/Dataset TA_1_spectrograms/spectrogram_B_2/val/014_twinkle_twinkle
Got 32 images from ./drive/MyDrive/1117002_Code Skripsi/Dataset/Dataset TA_1_spectrograms/spectrogram_B_2/val/014_twinkle_twinkle in 0.29237914085388184 seconds
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. it turns out that at this loop declaration:

```
for img_item in os.listdir(image_path):
```

`img_item` is actually the filename, and I do not need to add any more code.